# HTML homepage with footer

Tags: html, footer

Greetings for the day!

I am developing a demo website. This is my home page. I am dividing this page in 4 parts. I am successful in making top band and middle part as well. But, I am not been able to display the footer part. Below is the dashboard/home page html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- Header part -->
  <header>
   <center><h1>Shiksha University</h1></center>
  </header>


<!-- Center part -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
    left item1<br/>
    left item2<br/>
    left item3<br/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="right">
    right item1
    right item2
    right item3 
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .container {
      width:500px;
    }
    .left {
      width:250px;
      float:left;
    }
    .right {
      width:250px;
      float:right;
    }/style>


<!-- Footer part -->
<footer>
  <p>Posted by: Hege Refsnes</p>
  <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
  someone@example.com</a>.</p>
</footer>   
</body>
</html>
```

I am not been able to implement the footer part in the html page, kindly help :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the issue was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters your style tag isn't closed. Could be your issue

```
<style type="text/css">
.container {
  width:500px;
}
.left {
  width:250px;
  float:left;
}
.right {
  width:250px;
  float:right;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the "style" ;)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- Header part -->
  <header>
   <center><h1>Shiksha University</h1></center>
  </header>


<!-- Center part -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  left item1<br/>
  left item2<br/>
  left item3<br/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="right">
  right item1
  right item2
  right item3 
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
  .container {
    width:500px;
  }
  .left {
    width:250px;
    float:left;
  }
  .right {
    width:250px;
    float:right;
  }/style>

</style>
<!-- Footer part -->
<footer>
  <p>Posted by: Hege Refsnes</p>
  <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
  someone@example.com</a>.</p>
</footer>   
</body>
</html>
```